# Due to spaces between one Word Awk changed output

Tags: awk

Due to spaces between one Word Awk changed output

e.g : "Local Address" `awk` consider local and address Separately

```
# netstat -antulp | awk 'NR>1'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1115/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1397/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1271/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1473/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55547               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1133/rpc.statd
```

Output Should be : `$4 $5 $6`

```
Local Address   Foreign Address  PID/Program name
0.0.0.0:111     0.0.0.0:*         1115/rpcbind
0.0.0.0:22      0.0.0.0:*         1397/sshd
127.0.0.1:631   0.0.0.0:*         1271/cupsd
127.0.0.1:25    0.0.0.0:*         1473/master
0.0.0.0:55547   0.0.0.0:*         1133/rpc.statd
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to achieve? What is the problem?

Comment: Okay Janis , i am using below command but some how due to space between word ( Local Address ) there is spaces between Local and address word                                                                                           netstat -antulp | awk 'NR>1' | awk '{print $4 "   " $5 "   " $7}' | column -t                                                                                                               Local              Address               Address
0.0.0.0:111        0.0.0.0:*             1115/rpcbind
 Now check the first line it should be as per i share output in my 1sy query.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that information from your comment, and fix also the remaining inconsistencies in your question.

Answer (score 2):

From the awk manual:

> The awk utility shall interpret each input  record  as  a  sequence  of fields  where, by default, a field is a string of non-*blank* non-*newline* characters. This default *blank* and *newline* field delimiter can  be  changed  by using the FS built-in variable or the −F sepstring option.

You can change the behavious using the "-F" option or by setting the FS option in your awk code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $1 $2 $3}'
```

As far as how netstat does it's output I cannot answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
netstat -antulp |\
awk 'NR == 1 { skip } 
     NR == 2 { printf "%s %-19s\t%s %-18s\t%s %s\n",$4,$5,$6,$7,$9,$10} 
     NR >  2 { printf "%-24ss\t%-24ss\t%s\n",$4,$5,$6 ;}'
```

where

- first line skipped
- second line, I pick field you need (and adjust column size)
- all other line, print field with adjustement
- I fold the line for a better view, this could be one lined of course.

Comment: Thanks Archemar ,  but any simple method???

Comment: There is not a simple method just using awk fields, because the line you are working on does not have any characters other than spaces that could be used for a field delimiter. You could use the 'Q ' before Local and the F after address (in Foreign), using cut and awk, but it is getting a bit messy.